# How to create a bean of AADAuthenticationProperties (azure)?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, dependency-injection, azure-active-directory, spring-boot-starter

I cannot create a bean of AADAuthenticationProperties, and the reason sais that the property activeDirectoryGroups cannot be empty.

The error is the following:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'azure.activedirectory' to com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADAuthenticationProperties failed:

```
Property: azure.activedirectory.activeDirectoryGroups
Value: null
Reason: no puede estar vacío
```

This is the two ways a tried:

```
    //1st option
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public AADAuthenticationProperties aadAuthenticationPropertiesFactory() {
        return new AADAuthenticationProperties();
    }

    //2nd option
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public AADAuthenticationProperties aadAuthenticationPropertiesFactory() {
        AADAuthenticationProperties aadAuthenticationProperties = new AADAuthenticationProperties();
        aadAuthenticationProperties.setactiveDirectoryGroups(new ArrayList<>());
        return aadAuthenticationProperties;
}
```

But the error remains the same, so any idea about what is the activeDirectoryGroups property and how can I create a bean of AADAuthenticationProperties? I am using Java 8.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Delete the beans and just specify the properties in your `application.properties`. Those beans will be generated by the azure auto configuration. Your definition interferes with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like @M.Deinum said in the comment, you just need to specify the properties in your `application.properties`. The bean will be generated by the azure auto configuration. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory?view=azure-java-stable) for more details.

```
azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups=group1, group2
```